# Is it true that if $\partial^{m+1} f(x_0)$ exists then $\partial^{m} f(x)$ exists for all $x$ in the domain of $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, definition

I'm reading about higher derivative from textbook Analysis I by Amann.

> [image]

In this section, the author said that

> Suppose now that $m \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}$ and $\partial^{m-1} f: X \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{m-1}(E, F)$ is already defined.

In my understanding, "$\partial^{m-1} f: X \rightarrow \mathcal{L}^{m-1}(E, F)$ is already defined" means that $\partial^{m-1} f (x)$ exists for all $x \in X$. It follows from this statement that if $\partial^{m} f\left(x_{0}\right)$ exists then $\partial^{m-1} f\left(x\right)$ exists for all $x \in X$. Hence, we only define the $m$-th derivative at $x_0$ if the $(m-1)$-th derivative exists for all $x$ in the domain of $f$.

Could you please confirm if my understanding is correct? Thank you for your help!

Comment: For a function $f$ is differentiable at a point $x_0$ you need $x_0$ to be interior point of its domain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the given definition literally, what you have written is correct.  However, the given definition is not standard, since to define $\partial^mf(x_0)$, you really only need $\partial^{m-1}f(x)$ to be defined for all $x$ in some neighborhood $U$ of $x_0$, since that's all you need to define the derivative of $\partial^{m-1}f$ at $x_0$.  So, when most people talk about $\partial^mf(x_0)$, they do not require $\partial^{m-1}f$ to be defined everywhere, but only in a neighborhood of $x_0$.

(Very often this is a moot point because you want $\partial^mf$ to exist not just at a single point $x_0$ but at *every* point of $X$, in which case the two definitions are equivalent.)

Comment: Hi Eric, I posted a question about the relationship of total derivative and partial derivatives [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433412/find-the-formula-of-partial-j-partialm-fx-in-terms-of-partial-j-1). It seems to me that nobody's interested in this question. Could you please have a look at it? Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Honestly this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433412/compute-partial-j-partialm-fx-in-terms-of-partial-j-1-partial-j-2) is important to my understanding of higher derivative and higher partial derivatives. Please have a look at it!