# Compute $\partial_j (\partial^m f)(x)$ in terms of $\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_{m+1}} f(x)$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, derivatives, partial-derivative, multilinear-algebra

Good evening, I'm trying to do this exercise in preparation for the mid-term exam in analysis:

> Let $X$ be open in $\mathbb R^n$, $f:X \to F$, and $m \in \mathbb N$. Assume that $\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_{m+1}} f$ is continuous at $x$ for all $j_1, j_2, \ldots, j_{m+1} \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$ and $\partial^m f(x)$ is also continuous at $x$. For $j \in \{1,\ldots,n\}$, give the formula of $\partial_j (\partial^m f)(x)$ in terms of $\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_{m+1}} f(x)$.

Honestly, my proof is complicated with many formulas but I'm unable to reduce it anymore. The algebra of multilinear maps is a burden to me. This exercise is very important to me because it tests if I correctly understand the concepts of derivative and partial derivatives and their relationship.

I'm unable to determine if changing the order between $\lim_{t \to 0}$ and $\sup$ is right or wrong.

> $$\begin{aligned}& \lim_{t \to 0}  \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \| \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
> &  \quad \quad \quad  \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \|\\
> \le &   \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \| \lim_{t \to 0} \Bigg[ \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
> &  \quad \quad \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t} \Bigg]   -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \| \\
> \end{aligned}$$

As such, I very hope that somebody verifies my proof and give suggestions on it. Thank you so much for your help!

---

$\textbf{My attempt:}$

Let $\{e_1, \ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis of $\mathbb R^n$. We have $$\partial_{j_1} \partial_{j_2} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) = \partial^m f (x) [e_{j_1}, e_{j_2}, \ldots, e_{j_m}]$$ and so $$\begin{aligned}  \partial^m f (x) [h^1, \ldots, h^m] &=  \partial^m f (x) \left [\sum_{i=1}^n h_{i}^1 e_i, \ldots, \sum_{i=1}^n h_i^m e_i \right] \\ &= \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial^m f (x) \left [h^1_{j_1} e_{j_1}, \ldots, h^m_{j_m} e_{j_m} \right] \\ &= \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial^m f (x) \left [ e_{j_1}, \ldots, e_{j_m} \right]  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \\ &= \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})  \end{aligned}$$

for all $h^i = (h_1^i, \ldots, h_n^i) \in \mathbb R^n$ with $1 \le i \le m$. For each $x \in X$, we define a map $A_x$ by $$A_x: \mathbb R^m \to F, \quad A_x [h^1, \ldots,h^m] \mapsto \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) $$

We have $$\begin{aligned}
 &  \left \| \frac{\partial^m f(x +te_j) - \partial^m f(x)}{t} - A_x\right \| \\
=& \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1} \left \| \frac{\partial^m f(x +te_j) - \partial^m f(x)}{t} [h^1, \ldots,h^m] - A_x [h^1, \ldots,h^m] \right \| \\
=& \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1} \left \| \frac{\partial^m f(x +te_j)[h^1, \ldots,h^m] - \partial^m f(x) [h^1, \ldots,h^m]}{t}  - A_x [h^1, \ldots,h^m] \right \| \\
=& \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1} \Bigg \| \frac{ \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
&  \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad \frac{-  \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t} \\
& \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\quad  - \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n  \partial_j \partial_{j_1} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \| \\
=& \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1} \Bigg \|  \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg [ \frac{ \partial_{j_1} \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
&  \quad  \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg ]\Bigg \| \\
\le& \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \| \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
&  \quad \quad \quad   \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \|\\
\end{aligned}$$

Hence

$$\begin{aligned}
    & \lim_{t \to 0} \left \| \frac{\partial^m f(x +te_j) - \partial^m f(x)}{t} - A_x\right \| \\
\le & \lim_{t \to 0}  \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \| \frac{ \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
&  \quad \quad \quad  \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \|\\
\le &   \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \| \lim_{t \to 0} \Bigg[ \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t}  \\
&  \quad \quad \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m})}{t} \Bigg]   -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \| \\
\le &   \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \| (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \cdot \lim_{t \to 0} \Bigg[ \frac{  \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x + te_j) }{t}  \\
&  \quad \quad  \frac{- \quad \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)}{t}  \Bigg]  -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \|\\
= &   \sup_{|h^1|,\ldots,|h^m| \le 1}   \sum_{j_1, \ldots, j_m =1}^n \Bigg \|  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x) (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) -  \partial_j \partial_{j_1}  \cdots \partial_{j_m} f (x)  (h^1_{j_1} \cdots h^m_{j_m}) \Bigg \|\\
=& \quad 0
\end{aligned}$$

As such, $\partial_j (\partial^m f)(x) = A_x$.

Comment: You're misreading the problem. This is just a combinatorial exercise in giving an inductive form of the product rule. They're asking for partial derivatives of the power function $f^m$. I don't believe there's anything intended with multilinear maps. What you typed as Theorem 1 is obviously not a theorem, since it's an exercise; I believe the typo $\partial^m f$ appears there. (You can do this exercise with $n=1$, so that no partial derivatives appear. It's amusing to see the form of the answer.)

Comment: On second thought, maybe the other thing is the typo. What does $\partial^m f$ actually mean? You mean that this stands for the $m$th derivative as a multilinear map? ... Perhaps so. To be honest, I have no personal interest in belaboring these technicalities, so I will pass.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin It's actually a typo and $\partial^m f$ is the $m$-th Fréchet derivative of $f$. Anyway, thank you so much for responding to my S.O.S :)