# Is this hypothesis redundant in this version of Clairaut-Schwarz theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, partial-derivative

I'm reading a theorem about the symmetry of second partial derivatives in *Principles of Mathematical Analysis* by Prof. Rudin:

> **Theorem 9.41:** Suppose $f$ is defined in an open set $E \subseteq \mathbb R^{2},$ suppose that $D_{1} f$, $D_{21} f$, and $D_{2} f$ exist at every point of $E$, and $D_{21} f$ is continuous at some point $(a, b) \in E$. Then $D_{12} f$ exists at $(a, b)$ and
>   $$
> \left(D_{12} f\right)(a, b)=\left(D_{21} f\right)(a, b)
> $$

Before this theorem, the author defines second partial derivatives as follows:

> [image]

From my understanding, to define $D_{21} f (a)$, we must have $D_1 f$ exists in some neighborhood of $a$. As such, $D_{21} f$ exists at every point of $E$ implies that $D_{1} f$ exists at every point of $E$.

My question: Is the hypothesis that $D_{1} f$ exists at every point of $E$ is redundant in the **theorem 9.41**?

Thank you for your clarification?

Comment: Yes, of course, you're right, but the hypotheses are stated in a way to make things as clear and succinct as possible.

Comment: Thank you so much @TedShifrin, I asked this question because I'm just afraid that there's something subtle that I miss in the way the theorem is stated.

Comment: @TedShifrin I posted a question about the relationship of total derivative and partial derivatives [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3433412/compute-partial-j-partialm-fx-in-terms-of-partial-j-1-partial-j-2). It seems to me that nobody's interested in this question because the algebra of multilinear maps is too cumbersome. Honestly, that question reflects my understanding of higher derivative and higher partial derivatives. Could you please have a look at it? Thank you so much for your help!